# How do I autofill a range of cells with values, based on another cell's value? Is there an Excel's equivalent of GoogleSheet's arrayformula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, array-formulas

Edit:
1) I use O365
2) Google Formula
=ARRAYFORMULA((if(D3=Parameters!B12,Parameters!B13:B20,if(D3=Parameters!C12,Parameters!C13:C20,if(D3=Parameters!D12,Parameters!D13:D20,if(D3=Parameters!E12,Parameters!E13:E20,if(D3=Parameters!F12,Parameters!F13:F20)))))))

I was able to the the thing below in Google Sheets using Arrayformula and nested IFs, but how do I do it in Excel?

Say, A1 is a dropdown, and depending on what the user chooses for A1, I want A3 - A7 to automatically populate.

Examples

If A1=Cat, I want A3, A4, A5 to automatically populate with Tiger, Lion, and Lynx

If A1=K9, I want A3, A4, A5, A6, A7 to automatically populate with Wolf, Fox, Dog, Big Dog, and Good Boi

```
     |    A    |
1    |   Cat   |
2    |         |
3    |  Tiger  |
4    |  Lion   |
5    |  Lynx   |
6    |         |
7    |         |


     |    A    |
1    |    K9   |
2    |         |
3    |  Wolf   |
4    |  Fox    |
5    |  Dog    |
6    | Big Dog |
7    | Good Boi|
```

How can I do this in Excel?

Comment: Please post the google formula you are using.

Comment: Excel is different than Google.  It requires a formula in every cell that returns a value.  You need to highlight A3:A7 with A3 active.  Put just your IF function in the formula bar and hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter and Excel will put the formula in the rest of the cells and the output should be correct.

Comment: Are the items in the list hard coded in the formula or do they pull from another table?

Comment: @ScottCraner if OP is using the latest O365 and can use *dynamic arrays* (somewhat unlikely though), "It requires a formula in every cell that returns a value" is no longer true.

Comment: I was unaware of those, cool something new to learn.  @MathieuGuindon

Comment: @ScottCraner you an get a glimpse with teylyn's answer below - Leila Gharani has a number of [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2USJsIyIzvo) on the subject; check out [Oz' channel too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drJH7rOThLs)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon

I have O365, but not sure if it is the latest, and the values are referenced from another tab. 
Here's my google formula

=ARRAYFORMULA((if(D3=Parameters!B12,Parameters!B13:B20,if(D3=Parameters!C12,Parameters!C13:C20,if(D3=Parameters!D12,Parameters!D13:D20,if(D3=Parameters!E12,Parameters!E13:E20,if(D3=Parameters!F12,Parameters!F13:F20)))))))

Comment: In Excel you make an "array formula" by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon but i'd have to always do that when there is a new value in A1.... I'm going to shoot for the dynamic array thing. Thanks!

Comment: No you don't have to re-enter the array formula when the value in A1 changes.

Answer (score 2):

The technique depends on which version of Excel you have.

Excel without the new Dynamic Array formulas will require you to pre-fill the cells with a formula that looks up the value.

With the new Dynamic Arrays (currently only available in Office 365 Insider), you can have just one formula in A3 and it will spill down automatically. In the screenshot, the formula is only in A3, nothing has been copied down.

[image]

Comment: Ah! too bad i do not have insider!!!! i'm going to ask my company to give me that license. thank you so much!

Comment: @song note that other versions of Excel won't be able to compute dynamic array functions - if you need to share the file, hacking it up with regular (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) array formulas is probably a better idea. OTOH insider builds are great for seeing what's coming to Excel before everyone else, and providing direct feedback and submit bugs to the Excel devs at Microsoft!